# IIS: Presenting static content before ASP.NET app first load?

Tags: asp.net, iis

As you know, when you have a complex ASP.NET application, the first page load in IIS is slow due to JIT compilation.

The common trick is to warm the application up using some new IIS features and/or external scripts that leave the site alive.

We wondered if it would be possible to have a simple HTML page which would be presented temporarily during this first load. For the sake of discussion, imagine this is the first load when the machine boots up - it is impossible to warm up beforehand.

This HTML page simply presents a loading message before launches an AJAX request to the regular default.aspx page and, when this other page loads, it redirects there.

It appears that the application starts the first load JIT compilation before returning the static page, even if we point our HTML, images & scripts to use "StaticFileModule" as an HTTP Handler.

Anyone ever manage to accomplish this without using two different ASP.NET applications (where the temporary one would have nothing except the static content)? This technique works, but I'd like to have everything self-contained.

Comment: Your idea of using two applications sounds fine. Have you tried to implement it? Did it not work?

Comment: Tested after posting this message; confirms it works. Will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plain `.html` file in your application should load instantly even if the site is cold.

You can have this static page have a message with a 0 delay meta redirect in it that starts loading the next page that fires up the site and when it's done the next page should load.

Just make sure that there isn't a handler registered for that `.html` filetype that fires the warmup that would make it slow too.

**See also:**

- http://www.devtoolshed.com/globalasax-events-iis-6-and-iis-7-static-resources

Comment: So if I am not seeing this behaviour now, there is something overriding the StaticFileModule HTTP handler that is explicitly defined?

Comment: @JasonKealey, do you specify any handler for it? What if you don't? Are you using MVC routes?

Comment: <add name="Static Html" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" />  With and without this: same behaviour. I guess I'll assume something else is kicking in (as this is a complex application with many things that could interact with the above)

Comment: Do you have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`? Also, make sure you test with IIS because I read: `These code samples will run great in your Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 Cassini built-in web server, but if you deploy them to a standard IIS 6 or IIS 7 server, you will be scratching your head because your Global.asax events will not fire when static resources are requested.` and `In IIS 7, the .NET pipeline is fully integrated into IIS but by default, IIS does not serve static resources through your ASP.NET application. So your events will not fire for these types of resources.`